# How to prove that intersection of events is a partitioning

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading the book by prof. Tsitsiklis and the solution guide states the following:

$(B^c\cap C^c)\cup (B\cap C^c)\cup (B^c\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$ is a partitioning of $\Omega$.

It's not proved and intuitively it makes sense. But how can I prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General approach.** First show that they are distinct.  If $x \in P \cap Q$ (where $P$ is either $B$ or $B^c$ and $Q$ is either $C$ or $C^c$), then $x \in P$ and $x \in Q$.  Show that this precludes $x$ from being in any of the three other sets.

Then show that any element $x$ must be in one of the sets.  Either $x \in B$ or $x \in B^c$, and either $x \in C$ or $x \in C^c$.  Show by consideration of the four possible cases that $x$ must be in the appropriate set.